# Some PDEs to solve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $A=A(t,x),B=B(t,x), C=C(t,x)$ be arbitrary smooth function. Let $F=F(u,v)$ and $G=G(u,v)$.

Could anyone show me how the solutions of 
\begin{align}
2(BF_u-AF_v)-2B^2-B&=0\\
2(BG_u-AG_v)+2A^2+A&=0
\end{align}
are
\begin{align}
F&=\frac{2b+1}{2}u+f(r)\\
G&=\frac{2a+1}{2}v+g(r)
\end{align}
where $r=au+bv$, and $f,g$ are arbitrary smooth function of $r$. I can do this in Maple and Mathematica, I will be appreciated if someone can show me how to get the exact expression by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the so-called [Method of characteristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). (However, explanation on wiki is not complete enough, but you can find it somewhere else)

Note that your equations are actually independent of each other.
Therefore, I will show what to do only for the first equation.

Let us write the first equation in the form
$$
B F_u - A F_v = \frac{2 B^2 + B}{2}.
$$
Using the Method of characteristics, we write
$$
\frac{du}{B} = \frac{dv}{-A} = \frac{dF}{\frac{2 B^2 + B}{2}}.
$$
Therefore, we get two independent equations from here:
$$
\frac{du}{B} = \frac{dv}{-A} \quad \mbox{and} \quad \frac{d u}{B} = \frac{dF}{\frac{2 B^2 + B}{2}}.
$$
Simply integrating them, we get
$$
\frac{u}{B} + \frac{v}{A} = C_1 \quad \mbox{and} \quad \frac{2 B+1}{2} u - F = C_2.
$$
the Method of characteristics says that any function $\Phi(C_1, C_2) = 0$ will be a solution of your problem. Therefore, $C_2 = \varphi(C_1)$ with an arbitrary function $\varphi$ will be also a solution. Substituting $C_1$ and $C_2$ we get
$$
F = \frac{2B + 1}{2} u - \varphi \left(\frac{u}{B} + \frac{v}{A} \right),
$$
which is absolutely equivalent to your answer.

Comment: could you please give me a quick reference of the method of characteristics? other than evans' book on pre and wiki

Comment: @math101 look at this book https://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/436.A1.12f/PDE_Meth_Characteristics.pdf I don't know is it good enough, but there are a lot of examples and the rigorous proof of this method (Theorem 2.5)